# Coldfusion server stops rendering pages when accessed over Chrome for Android

Tags: android, apache, google-chrome, coldfusion

We have apache 2.4 running on a Windows Server 2012, everything works fine except one strange bug:

The server stops serving any pages to users after someone visits any page via Chrome for Android. The visitor on the Android device (only when using Chrome) gets an "connection reset" error, but all users after that are getting blank loading pages until Apache gets restarted. If an user is loading a page on any other device during a restart, the page finishes loading immediately.

It seems that i can't find anything specific in the Apache or CF errorlogs. The only error i'm able to find is in the coldfusion-out.log:

> Apr 15, 2016 13:34:43 PM Error [ajp-nio-8016-exec-15] - The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: cfhttp The specific sequence of files included or processed is: C:\projekte\removed\So-funktioniert-es-6.html, line: 98

It does mention a specific file here, but it happens no matter what file or page you try to open. It's a really strange bug and we can't find any solution to it, nor anyone else with the same problem. The server isn't overloaded at all.

Hopefully i was specific enough for someone to point us in the right direction.

Comment: That error in the log references an HTML file rather than a CFM. Do you have ColdFusion configured to process html files?

Answer (score 0):

The error **The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag** itself says what's wrong.

The above error means your page has taken too long to finish
processing, so ColdFusion has ended the process in order to free up the server.

If you have access to the administrator, you can increase the timeout period
server-wide in the Settings page (Timeout requests after n seconds) - if you
just want to increase the timeout period for that particular page, you can tack
on requestTimeout=x (where x is the number of seconds before the page times
out) to the url as below:

http://your_url?requestTimeout=desired_time_in_seconds

Alternatively you can use the tag `<cfsetting requestTimeOut = "desired_time_in_seconds">` within your
code to overide the default setting.

**Edit**: If it is occuring only on Chrome then there must be something that's breaking your request. Most probably Javascript, Ajax, Jquery. But try the above method first.

Comment: I disagree.  The requestTimeout controls how long cf has to process the cfml code.  This is client agnostic.  Also, a timeout on one page request does not affect subsequent page requests.